# How to access the intranet through internet?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, intranet

I have developed web application for intranet, I have developed on asp.net 4.0 and IIS server 6.0, database is on SQL Server 2008.

It is working fine in intranet, but we need to access this web application from internet. How can I do that?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/hosting/host_intro.asp

Answer (score 2):

You need to forward port (preferably 80) of public ip address to local ip address of your web server, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe as easy as some of the answers provided like port forwarding but in reality this question is a broad topic on networking:

1. Determine your public IP addressing setup (static? dynamic?)
2. DNS settings/setup
3. Network infrastructure - router? firewall?

Port forwarding and such is only after #3, when you need to setup your internal (network)  environment and make it "ready" for public access. Goes without saying this assumes you've completed setup of your IIS server - there are several ways to interpret `intranet application`....and that's not necessarily assumed to work for **public** access.